# body onload does not see js function on the same page

Tags: javascript

I am slightly baffled by this one... for some reason the `newLoaded()` function is apparently not defined and as per the console output I get this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: newLoaded is not defined at onload` yet it's literally on the same page (not even loaded via external resources)

```
<head>
...
<script language="text/javascript">
    function newLoaded() {
        loaded();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="newLoaded();" class="page page-id-105 page-template page-template-page-fullwidth page-template-page-fullwidth-php cherry-fixed-layout" style="height: 100%;margin:0px;padding:0px">
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i found out was the `language="text/javascript"` is deprecated. Either remove it or use `type=""`

I have tried following code and seems to be working good

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function newLoaded() {
            //loaded();
            alert();
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="newLoaded()">
    </body>
    </html>
```

also if there is any `load()` function whats not defined, the rest can't be triggered.

Comment: Yes - that seems to be the case. Recent migration to a newer server shows its pitfalls

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have a typo it should be `onload` not `onLoad`

EDIT: it works on both cases but the standard one all lowercase

Comment: Even though you're right, this is more of a comment then an answer since it doesn't fix OP's problem

Comment: 2 upvotes lol. It does not matter... It does the job in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for input - while you are right that the onload should be all lowercase - this isn't actually the root of the problem as it will work with both versions:)

Comment: yes the problem was with `language` attribute as describe by @Jayr